# Selected value in JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Could someone tell me how can I get amount of selected value in JList? I use MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION in my code to select more than one value.

Comment: Please check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852864/get-the-selected-values-from-jlist-in-java

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the `JList` API
2. There are two methods that start with `getSelected...()`. Pick one of the methods to use.
3. Create a loop that iterates through all the values returned from the above method
4. Convert each value to a number and add the number
5. display the total value.